# Incrementing a counter for a word in a list of words and counters

Tags: sml, smlnj

So i have a list of words and counters:

`[("word1", 1), ("word2", 1)]`

and I was wondering how I would increment the counter for a word i add into that list, for example:

- If the word was already in the list, increment the counter for that word:

  - `counts "word1" [("word1", 1), ("word2", 1)] => [("word1", 2), ("word2", 1)]`
- Otherwise create a new count in the list:

  - `counts "word3" [("word1", 1), ("word2", 1)] => [("word1", 1), ("word2", 1), ("word3", 1)]`

Here is the code i have tried so far:

```
fun counts w [] [(w, 1)]
  | counts w ((hd, n)::tl) =
      if(w hd) then (hd, n+1)::tl
      else if(not(w hd)) then [(hd, n)]@[(w, 1)]@tl
      else (hd, n)::tl;
```

I am getting the right output for the second case, but for the first case this is the output i get:

```
counts "the" [("cat", 1), ("the", 1)];
val it = [("cat",1),("the",1),("the",1)] : (string * int) list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the details mentioned by you, this should work:

```
fun count w [] = [(w, 1)]
| count w ((w', c)::tl) = 
    if w = w'
    then (w', c+1)::tl
    else (w', c)::(count w tl);

count "the" [("cat", 1), ("the", 1)];
count "word1" [("word1", 1), ("word2", 1)];
count "word2" [("word1", 1), ("word2", 1)];
count "word1" [];
count "word1" [("word1", 1)];
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I half had it haha, got confused with the adding it onto the resulting list ^^